# Why is f(arg, superfluous_arg) an ArgumentError but f (arg, superfluous_arg) a SyntaxError?

Tags: ruby, syntax, arguments, whitespace

In Ruby 1.9.3, I have a function with a single argument. If I call it correctly, it works either with or without whitespace separating its name and parenthesis. If I pass an extra argument, it fails in two different ways. Why?

```irb
irb(main):001:0> def f(a); a; end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> f(1)
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> f(1, 2)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
        from (irb):1:in 'f'
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
irb(main):004:0> f (1)
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> f (1, 2)
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
f (1, 2)
     ^
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
irb(main):006:0> RUBY_DESCRIPTION
=> "ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first error:

```
>> f(1, 2)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

...is pretty straightforward, you're passing exactly one argument too many.

#### Let's concentrate on the second error!

```
>> f (1, 2)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>> f((1, 2))
```

Which is also invalid syntax. This is because:

```
(1, 2)
```

...isn't a valid expression either. You can see this more simply like this:

```
>> 1, 2
SyntaxError: (irb):9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
```

#### Why does `f (1)` work?

Well `(1)` simply evaluates to `1`:

```
>> (1)
=> 1
```

#### What does this all mean?

[Method calls](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Method_Calls) look like this "`method_name(parameter1, parameter2, …)`" (with no space before the opening parenthesis) or like this "`method_name parameter1, parameter2, …`" (with no parentheses at all).

Mixing spaces and parentheses is likely to lead to unexpected behaviour somewhere down the line, as you have seen.

Comment: The standard style for calling methods is either `f(1,2)` with no space, or `f 1,2` with no brackets. There is no other way that will work reliably. People that put spaces between functions and their arguments can get tons of warnings that their code might not work as expected, and this answer indicates why.

Comment: Warnings! I should have enabled warnings: `irb -w` says "warning: `(...)` interpreted as grouped expression" when evaluating `f (1)`.